# Frontend using TailwindCSS, Vite and postcss with a MERN stack project won't show webpage elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, mern

I am building a website backend and frontend using MERN and I have finished the backend and it is now the frontend's turn to be developed.

I am using Vite, TailwindCSS and PostCSS with of course React.js. So I have built my App.jsx and built my components, sections and got some assets and, till now, nothing is executing with an error or a warning. But the localhost webpage isn't showing a single element, or background or anything.

Here is my `App.jsx`:

```
import { CustomerReviews, Footer, Hero, Popular, Services, SpecialOffers, Subscribe, SuperQuality } from "./sections";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";

const App = () => {
  
  <main className="relative">
    <Nav />

    <section className="xl:padding-1 wide:padding-r padding-b">
      <Hero />
    </section>

    <section className="padding">
      <Popular />
    </section>

    <section className="padding">
      <SuperQuality />
    </section>

    <section className="paddin-x py-10">
      <Services />
    </section>

    <section className="padding">
      <SpecialOffers />
    </section>

    <section className="bg-pale-blue padding">
      <CustomerReviews />
    </section>

    <section className="padding-x sm:py-32 py-16 w-full">
      <Subscribe />
    </section>

    <section className="bg-black padding-x padding-t pb-8">
      <Footer />
    </section>
  </main>
};

export default App;
```

Here is my `main.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'
import './index.css'
import App from './App.jsx'
console.log('App has started!')

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

And here is one of the sections I have (they all follow the same pattern):

```
const Hero = () => {
  console.log("Hero.jsx: Hero")
  return (
    <div>TEST</div>
  )
}

export default Hero
```

I have opened the Inspect tool in my browser and no warnings or errors are there. Also as you can see in `Hero.jsx` file (last code block), I wrote a console.log, funny enough it doesn't print it in the console, however the console.log in `main.jsx` is working just fine.

Imports, paths, config files to all mentioned and where the console.log is are all correct (I think).

I appreciate any help I can get because I can't seem to find where the problem lies.

NOTE: I tried wrapping the App in a `return(/* content */)` but didn't work either.

Still, webpage is as white as snow.

Edit 1: when I write something it doesn’t show, also When I change the  to  it shows the content of Hero in the webpage.

I tried the bracketing thing but it made no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered where the problem is, in my  component there are somethings that are causing it to prohibit display of anything. So if I put a working component like the Hero component instead of Nav under the <main className:”relative”> line. So Nav contains something off.

Here is Nav (Still not done but should show something):

```
import { headerLogo } from '../assets/images'
import {hamburger} from '../assets/icons'
import { navLinks } from '../constants'

const Nav = () => {
    console.log('Nav has started!')
  return (
    <header className='padding=x py-8 absolute z-10 w-full'>
        <nav className='flex justify-between items-center max-container'>
            <a href="/">
                <img 
                src={headerLogo} 
                alt="logo"
                width={130}
                height={29}
                />
            </a>
            <ul className='flex-1 flex justify-center items-center gap-y-16 max-lg:hidden'>
                {navLinks.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                        <a 
                        href='item.href'
                        className='font-montserrat leading-normal text-lg text-slate-gray'
                        >
                            {item.label}
                        </a>
                    </li>))}

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Nav
```